# Problems with reusing LEFT JOIN results in WHERE and ORDER BY Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT s.*,
u.username,
u.fullname,
c.title AS ctitle,
c.description AS cdescription,
sa.attention,
sp.popularity,
COUNT(DISTINCT f.id) AS favorites,
COUNT(DISTINCT st.id) AS stars,
COUNT(DISTINCT v.id) AS views
FROM shots s
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = s.user_id
INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = s.cat_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN(
    SELECT shot_id, round(AVG(count),2) AS attention
    FROM points 
    WHERE date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 DAY)
    GROUP BY shot_id
) sa ON sa.shot_id = s.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN(
    SELECT shot_id, SUM(count) AS popularity
    FROM points 
    GROUP BY shot_id
) sp ON sp.shot_id = s.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN favorites f ON f.shot_id = s.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN stars st ON st.shot_id = s.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN views v ON v.shot_id = s.id
**WHERE s.library = 1 AND sa.attention > 40
ORDER BY sa.attention DESC
LIMIT 0,50**
GROUP BY s.id
```

I can't use the `sa.attention` in a condition and for ordering. Why?
(I removed the marked part, and the query works!)

What do I have to change in my Query? And if you could give a explanation for it, that would be very nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are negating your `OUTER JOIN` by putting that in your `WHERE` criteria.  Move it to your `JOIN` and you'll get your `NULL` records back:

```
SELECT s.*,
    u.username,
    u.fullname,
    c.title AS ctitle,
    c.description AS cdescription,
    sa.attention,
    sp.popularity,
    COUNT(DISTINCT f.id) AS favorites,
    COUNT(DISTINCT st.id) AS stars,
    COUNT(DISTINCT v.id) AS views
FROM shots s
    INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = s.user_id
    INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = s.cat_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN(
        SELECT shot_id, round(AVG(count),2) AS attention
        FROM points 
        WHERE date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 DAY)
        GROUP BY shot_id
    ) sa ON sa.shot_id = s.id AND sa.attention > 40
    LEFT OUTER JOIN(
        SELECT shot_id, SUM(count) AS popularity
        FROM points 
        GROUP BY shot_id
    ) sp ON sp.shot_id = s.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN favorites f ON f.shot_id = s.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN stars st ON st.shot_id = s.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN views v ON v.shot_id = s.id
WHERE s.library = 1 
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY sa.attention DESC
LIMIT 0,50
```

A second note, `GROUP BY` cannot go at the end.  I moved that to the correct spot as well.